# Parent and Child Class

Tags: c#

I have the following code.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Employee FTE = new FullTimeEmployee();
    }

}

public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    public void PrintFullName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(FirstName + " " + LastName);
    }
}

public class FullTimeEmployee : Employee
{
    public float YearlySalary;
}
```

I just want to clarify one thing.

If I write `Employee FTE = new FullTimeEmployee();` is the object created only able to access the FirstName,LastName,PrintFullName and NOT YearlySalary?

And if I write `FullTimeEmployee FTE = new FullTimeEmployee();` is the object created able to access everything INCLUDING YearlySalary?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just try this out?

Comment: I just want to make sure if I understood it right.

Comment: Sorry to confuse you, but "the object created" is a `FullTimeEmployee` in both cases. You *assign* (a reference to) it to a variable that can either handle an `Employee` or a `FullTimeEmployee` depending on how you declare it. If you declare the variable as `Employee`, then you can not access the `YearlySalary` field of the object through that variable (directly). But that field still exists on that object. And it would be as easy as `((FullTimeEmployee)FTL).YearlySalary` to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any case the object is a `FullTimeEmployee` if you create it via `new FullTimeEmployee();`. But you have without casting only access to the declaring type. So if you declare it like: `FullTimeEmployee FTE =` you have full access, if you declare it like `Emplyee FTE` you have not. But you can simply cast it back.

First solution:

```
Employee FTE = new FullTimeEmployee();
var employee = (FullTimeEmployee)FTE;
var sal = employee.YearlySalary;
```

Second solution

```
Employee FTE = new FullTimeEmployee();
var employee = (FTE as FullTimeEmployee)
var sal = employee.YearlySalary;
```

This should both work. The difference between this two is, that `as` will not throw an exception if casting fails, it will just return null.

In your case you could take a look at the `var` keyword.